# How to build a "DELETE ... CASCADE" using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, cascade

I don't find anywhere how to build a generic "DELETE ... CASCADE" using sqlalchemy. A simple "DELETE" is as simple as:

```
User.query.filter(User.id == 1).delete()
# DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = %(id_1)s
```

That `delete()` call does not accept an additional parameter to enable the "CASCADE" suffix.

Most of the documentation around cascading deletes assumes that I have the model instantiated and cascading relationships referenced, and I can simply do `session.delete(user)`, but in my case, not only don't I have the model instance, but I'd also like to build the query for a group of ids (using `query.in_`), And I'd prefer to forego instantiating models-then delete them 1 by 1.

I assume this is possible somehow, even if via the query expression API, although I've also not been succcessful there:

```
users_table.delete().where(users_table.c.id == 1)
```

Comment: i think x = users_table.delete().where(users_table.c.id == 1) then x.execute() should do it

Comment: this does not add "... CASCADE" to the resulting query though, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html oh yeah sorry that should be on the relationship in your model

Comment: yup, all documentation I found supposes you're deleting an entity, not that you're firing an SQL query directly with an id.